# Using both desktop Powershell 5.1 and Powershell Core 6.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I was playing with PS.Core 6.1 in my VS Code - made it the default shell, opened PS debugging sessions with it, opened its console, etc ...

Now I am opening the regular desktop Powershell 5.1 and get this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\me> get-module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PS...


PS C:\Users\me> $env:PSModulePath -split ';'
C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
c:\program files\powershell\6\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PS C:\Users\me>
```

This is not good. The PS.Core 6.1 installed its own `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` module which is incompatible with the desktop version.

The PSModulePath environment variable now lists the PS.Core 6 modules alongside the desktop modules, even with higher priority. Even though I do not see it in the Control Panel:

[image]

What a mess.

**EDIT 1**

The mess I observe is when I launch the shells from the shortcuts I have in the taskbar. The desktop one targets **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe** and the core one - **"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe" -WorkingDirectory ~**

**EDIT 2**

So, somehow, either installation of PS.Core or my experimentation with VS.Code has updated the environment of the parent explorer.exe process. I describe it here - [How does PSModulePath environment property get composed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888806/how-does-psmodulepath-environment-property-get-composed)

Could be a bug in the installation of PS.Core, which means it is a one time thing. Or a bug in VS Code, which means I could screw it again.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure you are launching PowerShell 5.1? e.g. by running `powershell.exe`. PowerShell 6.1 is launched with `pwsh.exe`. Can you run `$PSVersionTable` to verify you are launching the right version? The screenshot sure looks like you are launching PowerShell 6.1.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` returns `5.1.17763.503` for desktop and `6.2.1` for PS.Core

Comment: Setting your default on VS Code has nothing to do with the issue and is irrelevant (not sure why that was mentioned). I would recommend uninstalling PS 6, making sure PS 5.1 operates normally and then try installing PS 6 again.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - Well, there are only two things I did - install PS.Core 6.1 and play with it in VS Code. One of them modified the environment of the parent explorer.exe process which affects any future powershells I run from the TaskBar shortcut. That is what I know. Hence I cannot exclude VS Code.

Comment: VS Code settings are stored in a `settings.json` file. There is no mechanism for it to modify environment variables for PS5.1 or PS6.

Comment: In VS Code setting the deafult shell for the terminal simply adds this entry to your settings.json file (and that is all it does): `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6\\pwsh.exe"`

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be setting PowerShell Core 6.1 as your default shell.

If I launch PowerShell 5.1 (powershell.exe) from cmd prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2879
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.2879
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility


    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}
```

I get the expected module version.

If I launch PowerShell Core 6.1 (pwsh.exe) from cmd prompt:

```
C:\>pwsh.exe
PowerShell 6.1.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.1.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.1.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0


PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility


    Directory: C:\program files\powershell\6\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                --------- ----------------
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        Core      {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Forma...
```

I get the expected module version.

Now, if I launch PowerShell Core 6.1 from cmd prompt first, **then** launch PowerShell 5.1 from PowerShell Core 6.1 (i.e. as if you set your default shell to PowerShell Core 6.1):

```
C:\>pwsh.exe
PowerShell 6.1.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.1.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.1.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0


PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility


    Directory: C:\program files\powershell\6\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                --------- ----------------
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        Core      {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Forma...


PS C:\> powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2879
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.2879
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility


    Directory: C:\program files\powershell\6\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}


    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}
```

I get **both** modules listed. And when I import the module:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
PS C:\> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-ItemPropert...
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl...
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Connect-WSMan, Disable-WSManCredSSP, Disconnect-WSMan, En...
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PS...
```

The newer version (6.1) is loaded!

I agree that this is unexpected.

The good news is that we can access the old module as well, by specifying the `-MaximumVersion`:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility -MaximumVersion 3.1.0.0
PS C:\> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   6.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-ItemProperty...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler...}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "default shell"? The mess I am observing is when I open powershell from the shortcut I have in the taskbar.

Comment: @mark What keeps you from checking which version is invoked by the taskbar shortcut and insert another shortcut? That's the way I use both, keep in mind that the profile pathes differ => `$profile|fl * -force`

Comment: @LotPings - please, see **EDIT 2**. Are you referring to the first item - shared `$PROFILE`? If so are you suggesting to have the `$PROFILE` script determine the powershell version and load my own custom script based on the version? Sort of custom implementation of separate profile? BTW, the CurrentUser profiles do not differ, they are the same path both for desktop and core versions of PS.

Comment: Well, path entries are a problem, here v5.1 comes first. But the profiles do differ, here v5.1 has the subfolder `WindowsPowerShell` while v6.1.2 has only `PowerShell`. It's a matter of preference to either sync profiles manually or distinguish via variables `$PsEdition`,`$IsLinux`,`$IsMacOS`,`$IsWindows` and eventually `$PSVersionTable.OS`. ATM I'm working on ALL platforms, including Ubuntu and RaspBian.

Comment: @LotPings - I am terribly sorry. All the profiles are different. Stupid me. I have changed **EDIT 2** to remove the embarrassingly false statements. I think all I need is to check again if I can poison the environment of explorer.exe by either installing PS.Core or playing with VS Code.