# How does PSModulePath environment property get composed?

Tags: powershell

This question is related to my other post - [Using both desktop Powershell 5.1 and Powershell Core 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875328/using-both-desktop-powershell-5-1-and-powershell-core-6-1)

Basically the root of the evil is that when I open a desktop Powershell and check `$env:PSModulePath` I see PS.Core module path there.

Please, observe:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\me> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.503
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.503
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\Users\me> $env:PSModulePath -split ';'
C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
c:\program files\powershell\6\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PS C:\Users\me>
```

Notice `c:\program files\powershell\6\Modules`.

Now when I inspect the Environment variables in the Control Panel I see a different picture:

**User**

[image]

**System**

[image]

I do not even have the `$PROFILE` script:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Test-Path $PROFILE
False
PS C:\Users\me>
```

As one can see PS.Core 6.1 module path is not mentioned in the Control Panel, yet it is found in the actual PSModulePath environment variable.

So, my question is - how is PSModulePath truly composed?

I could not find it in the Microsoft documentation (I mean I did find it is an environment variable, but as one can see there is more to it). I must be missing something obvious.

**EDIT 1**

I opened Process Explorer and checked the environment of the parent process - explorer.exe. Its PSModulePath is:

```
C:\Users\mkharitonov\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
c:\program files\powershell\6\Modules
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

But after killing the explorer.exe and running it again, I can see the PS.Core module path disappeared. And so reopening the Powershell shows proper module path.

I suppose when I installed PS.Core 6.1 it modified the environment of the explorer.exe somehow. Or was it VS Code? Anyway, restarting the explorer fixes the issue.

I will have to dig into it and open a bug either to PS.Core or VS Code.

Comment: [Read the source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a96b4c040492e4e8f79ba243af6d43206fcd8791/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Modules/ModuleIntrinsics.cs) :-D Although it looks like it should still inherit the process-level env var, weird

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - your observation led me to the solution. See **EDIT 1**. Please, arrange your comment as the answer so I could credit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PowerShell starts up it'll attempt to [set the `PSModulePath` env var](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/a96b4c040492e4e8f79ba243af6d43206fcd8791/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Modules/ModuleIntrinsics.cs#L1348) by:

1. Reading the existing value of `%PSModulePath%` from the host process
2. Reading default module paths for the current user and for all users from the host application's config
3. If on Windows, reading the `%windir%\system32` module folder as well
4. Update the value of `$env:PSModulePath` by combining all three

If you see an unexpected value in there, `pwsh.exe` might have simply inherited it frmo the parent process and it's included in step 1

Comment: Correction - my problem is with `powershell.exe`, not `pwsh.exe`. But I guess they screw up each other if they somehow modify the environment of the parent explorer process.